# how to add a load balancer to an ec2 instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, cloud, load-balancing

I am developing inside an **ec2 instance** and I just added a **load balancer** to **ec2** using **terraform** but now i am getting a **504 Gateway Time-out**  error message on the browser when i try to access the **load balancer dns address**, also i noticed that **the target group** is unhealthy so the health check fail.

I have the following `load balancer` configuration:

```
resource "aws_lb" "alb" {
  name               = "backend-lb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.lb_sg.id]
  idle_timeout       = 60
  subnets            = [element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, 0), element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, 1)]
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "alb_target_group" {
  name        = "backend-tg"
  port        = 8000
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  health_check {
    enabled = true
    path = "/"
    port = "8000"
    protocol = "HTTP"
    healthy_threshold = 3
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    interval = 90
    timeout = 20
    matcher = "200"
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb.alb]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "http" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.alb.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn

  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "one" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.ec2.private_ip
  port             = 8000
}
```

**please note** that i used `.private_ip` in `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` `target_id` because i was facing the error `Error: Error registering targets with target group: ValidationError: The IP address '....foo id or arn' is not a valid IPv4 address` when trying to use `.id` or `.arn`.

Is there something that i am doing wrong here, is it the appropriate way to add a **load balancer** to an **ec2 instance**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to fix the `target_type` in your `aws_lb_target_group`. Change it from `ip` to `instance`. Or just delete that setting since `instance` is the default.

Then target ID should be the ID of the instance, not the IP address. The code should be:

```
target_id        = aws_instance.ec2.id
```

---

After that if it still doesn't work you need to verify that the security group of the EC2 instance allows ingress on port `8000` from the load balancer, that software on the EC2 instance is actually listening for web requests on port `8000`, and that an `HTTP GET` request on port `8000` of the EC2 instance returns status code `200`.

Comment: Hey Mark B, maybe you have a better idea on why its not working, indeed the security group is listening to port 8000, when i check the `dns` of the load balancer on the browser i get a `Not Found: The requested resource was not found on this server`, when i change all the values `8000` to `80` i get a `502 error`. all the steps you mentioned above were updated in my codes. I can the ec2 Public IPv4 address on port `8000`, ec2 work fine but not the load balancer and health check. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to change those target group and health check settings back to port `8000`. The not found error sounds like the software you are running on the EC2 server isn't routing the request correctly to your website because it doesn't know how to handle the DNS name.

Comment: yes you are right, i just forgot to access the correct url `loadbalancerDNS/api/`...the only problem is actually the health check failing...must be related to the path thank you